# Get value of a specific key from Params with complex hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am developing an app for Facebook Messenger and I am getting this params from Messenger. I want to take these params and store sender, text and other data. But I am unable get these params in controller.

When I try `params[:text]` it doesnt work, if I try `params[:entry][:messaging][1]` or anything like this doesnt work.

```
{"object":"page",
  "entry":[
    {
      "id":"PAGE_ID",
      "time":1460245674269,
      "messaging":[
        {
          "sender":{
            "id":"USER_ID"
          },
          "recipient":{
            "id":"PAGE_ID"
          },
          "timestamp":1460245672080,
          "message":{
            "mid":"mid.1460245671959:dad2ec9421b03d6f78",
            "seq":216,
            "text":"hello"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you can just tell me how to write my controller so I can grab value from [:text] it would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: there should be object name or u have to assign it. post your fetching method here.

Comment: params is equal to the Hash that you are showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simple parse your JSON and crawl until you reach specified key *in your case is you want to get text key*.

Do it with this:

I assume that the JSON you get is assigned to `json_value` variable:

```
json_value = '{"object":"page",
  "entry":[
    {
      "id":"PAGE_ID",
      "time":1460245674269,
      "messaging":[
        {
          "sender":{
            "id":"USER_ID"
          },
          "recipient":{
            "id":"PAGE_ID"
          },
          "timestamp":1460245672080,
          "message":{
            "mid":"mid.1460245671959:dad2ec9421b03d6f78",
            "seq":216,
            "text":"hello"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

Next, parse the JSON:

```
json = JSON.parse(json_value)
```

Then now, you can get the value of want you want with:

```
json["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["message"]["text"]
```

Output:

```
=> "hello"
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/CFtm)